# what's the difference between LinkedBlockingQueue and PriorityBlockingQueue?

Tags: java, concurrency

I need to create a producer-consumer realtionshiop using two threads. One is reading text objects from files on disk and then inserts objects into a queue in FIFO, and a consumer thread is reading from the queue to process the objects. However I'm confused as what class to use? LinkedBlockingQueue or PriorityBlockingQueue? Or even something better?

Goal & purpose:

I'm trying to cluster tweets in real-time, however I have the tweets in csv files archived and not using the Twitter Streaming API. So I'm trying to simulate the effect of the stream by reading tweets from files and putting them in a queue and then a consumer starts reading from the queue. I have really really large csv files, so thus I have more like a streaming scenario. So While I'm getting tweets in, a consumer is getting tweets from the queue and cluster them in real-time.

Comment: You haven't told us enough about your specific requirements to make your question answerable.  If you don't need to reorder the items in the queue by priority, a `LinkedBlockingQueue` should suffice.

Comment: Have you read the respective javadocs? The two implementations are fairly specific and different. Which characteristics seem to best fit your use case?

Comment: If you need priority, use the one that Implements it. If you need FIFO, use the other one. It's not difficult.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is the question in the title not specific enough? not being sarcastic

Comment: @Stephan: The question in the title can be easily answered by reading the docs, so there must be more to it than that.

Comment: I assume if there isn't much details, just pick the simplest option.

Comment: @RobertHarvey See edit - would be nice to be notified wouldn't it? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I think the answer is still the same: us a Priority queue if you need to reorder the items, and an ordinary blocking queue if you don't.

Answer (score 3):

PriorityBlockingQueue does not seem to make sense in your case since you simply want to process the messages in their original order.

If you really want to handle the queue yourself, you can use a bounded LinkedBlockingQueue:

```
//example with a limit of 100,000 messages being in the queue at any one time
private static final BlockingQueue<Message> queue =
                                      new LinkedBlockingQueue<> (100_000);
```

In the producer you keep doing:

```
Message msg = getMessage();
queue.put(msg); //blocks if the queue is full
```

and in the consumer:

```
Message msg = queue.take(); //blocks until there is a message
```

---

Peter Lawrey's alternative consists in doing:

```
private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

in your producer:

```
final Message msg = getMessage();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { process(msg); }
}
executor.submit(task);
```

And there is no comsumer since your producer has created it (the task).

---

Note: In the threadpool example, I used a size of 10 threads based on the assumption that the `process` method is mostly CPU-bound and you have around 10 processors. In practice:

- if it is the case (CPU-bound), you would use `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` to get the number of processors instead of a harcoded number.
- if not (I/O bound) you would use more threads - the optimal number is difficult to estimate beforehand and you would need to profile you app with different numbers to find the optimal value.

Comment: I think it will be less expensive to create a few consumers that will read the data from some queue(bounded to 100_000 in your case) than creating a pool for 100_000 threads to achieve the same effect. Because in case of ExecutorService producer thread has to wait for free thread in a pool to process the message

Comment: @maks I never mentioned creating a pool of 100,00 threads (which would probably crash any normally sized JVM/OS). My example with a thread pool uses 10 threads, which is based on the assumption that the consumer side is mostly CPU-bound and the machine has about 8 cores. I should probably have been more specific about that assumption.

Comment: you understood me uncorrectly... I mean that if you have 10 threads in a pool and if sometimes speed of incoming requests is higher than 10 messages at a time then 11th and other requests will wait for thread in a pool to be free. However, if you have 10 threads(consumers) that read messages(put there by producer) from some queue overall performance can be higher

Comment: @maks ok I understand - I think my update addresses that concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can LinkedBlockingQueue but its usually simpler to use an ExecutorService which wraps up the queue and a thread pool.  You can just submit a task to it for each job.

A PriorityBlockingQueue is for setting priorities on tasks.

I would look at the examples in the documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: which ExecutorService does that? Can you please edit your answer with some example code?

Comment: You can use any of them. You don't have a enough details to pick one over another.

Comment: in case of ExecutorService one can not be sure the ordering of the messages to be put in queue. To ensure the ordering ArrayBlockingQueue has to be used with fair parameter set to true in constructor